# How to get a Greasemonkey script's original installation URL?

Tags: greasemonkey

I have a site running in a few environments on different URLs (i.e. *dev.mysite.com*, *qa.mysite.com*, *uat.mysite.com*, etc).
There is a Greasemonkey script (*myGM.user.js*) at each of the environments but its version can be different and depending on the environment a different web service needs to be called to get some data.

In my user script, I would like to get the URL from which that user script was originally installed, so I could then extract the host and use it as a prefix for my web service URL.

For example, if my script is installed from
    `http://dev.mysite.com/myGM.user.js`,
I want to get
    `http://dev.mysite.com/myGM.user.js`,
 extract
    `http://dev.mysite.com/`
from it and call
    `http://dev.mysite.com/myWebService/getData`
for data.

What's the easiest way to accomplish that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up adding an ASPX page (could be PHP or whatever) to the same folder as `myGM.user.js`. It simply determines the current host (server-side) and outputs it as text.

So if you browsed to
`http://dev.mysite.com/getHost.aspx`
the response would be
`http://dev.mysite.com/`
And if you browsed to
`http://uat.mysite.com/getHost.aspx`
response would be
`http://uat.mysite.com/`

Then, in my `myGM.user.js` I've added
`// @resource rootUrl GetSiteRoot.aspx`
This resource directive takes a URL relative to the URL from where the user script is installed from and downloads the response alongside user script itself.

This allows me to call
`GM_getResourceText('rootUrl')`
in the body of the user script and know exactly where my script was installed from w/o having to make any changes from environment to environment.

P.S. I will, however, submit a feature request for this to be added GM_Info API.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Greasemonkey add-on records the script's original installation URL, this information is not available to the Greasemonkey script.

It seems like something that should be provided by [GM_info](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_info), but it isn't.  You can [try opening a feature request](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues?state=open).

The only **workaround**, for now, is to have slightly different versions of the script, in each place. (*Which you, admittedly, already do.*)  Specifically, add and change one line in the script's [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).
You can use [the `@downloadURL` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40downloadURL), like so:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YOUR SCRIPT
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @downloadURL http://qa.mysite.com/myGM.user.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

Or create your own directive, like so:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            YOUR SCRIPT
// @include         http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @myInstallLocale http://dev.mysite.com/myGM.user.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

The script would read the location like so:

```js
var dwnloadURL   = "";
var dwnldURLMtch = GM_info.scriptMetaStr.match (/\n\s*\/\/\s+@downloadURL\s+(.+?)\s*\n/i);
if (dwnldURLMtch  &&  dwnldURLMtch.length) {
    dwnloadURL   = dwnldURLMtch[1];
}
console.log (dwnloadURL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I would, however, prefer to keep the same version of `myGM.user.js` exactly the same across environments. I've came up with a different solution and will post it below.

Comment: Understandable, but you ***did*** say, "`but its (myGM.user.js) version can be different...`". ;)